# Linux Kernel Implementation

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I am implementing network layer to aggregate  2 network interface by dividing data to send them on 2 interfaces and combine it on the receiving end. I have achieved it in socket programming(c) but now I have to implement it on kernel in Ubuntu. I cant figure out where to start as i do not have any prior knowledge of kernel programing. Can anyone guide me about any helpful tutorials or demos so i can start working on it.

Comment: The Linux kernel is written in C, not C++. Use a search engine and books, Stack Overflow is not a substitute for those.

Comment: Linus Torvalds might use some harsh language if you say that you are using C++ to program linux kernel mate :-)

Comment: I believe you can find a tutorial or two [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+kernel+programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at network interface bonding.